The GET method is not supported for route registrar-articulo. Supported methods: POST - axios post
I am working on a project with laravel 9.
I have a problem with a request in axios, I get the following error:

405 Method Not Allowed

I have already applied the following commands in my project:
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:clear
npm run build

But the error persists.
This problem only occurs with one specific request, it is with the add record request.

js file
 var fileInput = document.getElementById('formFile');
      var file = fileInput.files[0];

      const formData = new FormData();
      // Agregar el archivo al FormData
      formData.append('imageFile', file, file.name);
      formData.append('nombre', nombre);
      formData.append('url', url);
      formData.append('fechaPublicacion', fechaPublicacion);
      formData.append('horaPublicacion', horaPublicacion);
      formData.append('tiempoLectura', tiempoLectura);
      formData.append('textoResumen', textoResumen);
      formData.append('temaId', temaId);
      formData.append('activoPost', activoPost);
      formData.append('detalleDataPost', JSON.stringify(detalleDataPost));
      formData.append('postRelacionados', JSON.stringify(arrayPostIds));

      axios.post(baseUrl+"/registrar-articulo", formData, {
        headers: { 
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.CSRF_TOKEN,
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      })
      .then(function(response) {

Controller
public function regitrarArticulo(Request $request){
        $msg = "";
        $exito = 0;

        $nombre = $request->get("nombre");
        $url = $request->get("url");
        $fechaPUblicacion = $request->get("fechaPublicacion");
        $horaPublicación = $request->get("horaPublicacion");
        $tiempoLectura = $request->get("tiempoLectura");
        $textoResumen = $request->get("textoResumen");
        $temaId = $request->get("temaId");
        $activoPost = $request->get("activoPost");
        $detallePost = $request->get('detalleDataPost');
        $postRelacionados = json_decode($request->get('postRelacionados'), true);
        $usuarioAgrego = Auth::user()->id;
        $fechaFinal = $fechaPUblicacion." ".$horaPublicación.":00";
        $imageName = '';
        $path = '';
        $imageName = time().'.'.$request->imageFile->extension();
        $path = $request->file('imageFile')->storeAs('images', $imageName, 'public');

        $articulosEncontrado = DB::table('posts')
        ->join('temas', 'temas.id', 'posts.tema_id')
        ->where('posts.urlpost', $url)
        ->where('temas.id', $temaId)
        ->get();
        if(count($articulosEncontrado) > 0){

Web.php
Route::post('/registrar-articulo', [PostController::class, 'regitrarArticulo'])->middleware('auth')->name('registrar-articulo');
Route::post('/modificar-articulo', [PostController::class, 'updatePost'])->middleware('auth')->name('modificar-articulo');

Route list

I think the problem is in how I make the request in axios, because I have to point out that I have another request that works for the modification using the post method, but this one responds correctly.
I need to know what is the error I have, or the consideration I am missing to apply to my project, to make it work correctly.

Answering my question, I discovered that what caused this error was one of the data that I sent in the form data, specifically the name, the name was registered with 2 parentheses, (Example), separately they did not cause anything, but when being in the same sentence the error occurred, so I applied encodeURIComponent to be able to send that information and a urldecode to receive it, and thus it was resolved.
I'm afraid I don't know the reason for this failure, I assumed that the formData should have been encoded as text and not have this problem.
I hope it helps someone else.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
